# Dividing two numbers

Tags: c#, variables

I'm doing some self-education in C#, and although I did more complex projects than this, I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int headcount = 0;
        int input = Global.inputcount;

        for (int i = 0; i < Global.inputcount; i++)
        {
            if (Global.myTextFile[i] == "F")
            {
                headcount++;
            }
        }
        float result;
        result = headcount/input; <<< that line
        button4.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

This is my code, its supposed to count how many times does `F` occour in the `myTextFile` array, and it should divide that number with the number of inputs.

I debugged it many times, and everything is fine until [that] line. Result is 0 despite the fact that (headcount = ~2201) and (input = ~4321).

I used to work with pascal, I've been using C# for like 2 months so if anyone can help me out i would be grateful.

`F` stands for "Fej" = "Head" in Hungarian

Comment: That's an integer division, use result = (float)headcount / input; instead.

Comment: problem is integer division. try casting to `result = (float)headcount/input;`

Comment: `int/int` = `int` - you need to cast the devisee (`headcount`) to `float`

Comment: Thank you very much! So i have to tell the IDE when im working with f.e. type a and expect type b as result?

Comment: There are so many related questions here that I wonder why any of them has not popped out while you were typing the title of this question.

Answer (score 6):

`int / int` performs [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) which *always* disregards fractional part *no matter* which type you assign it.

From [`/` Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2. To obtain a quotient as a rational
>   number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type
>   double.

You might wanna use floating-point division instead.

```
result = (float)headcount / input;
```

or

```
result = headcount / (float)input;
```

Check [7.7.2 Division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx) documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting a `INT` result and both the operands are `INT` type, you are getting `0` as output. You may want to convert that to `float` operation

```
headcount/(input * 1.0);
```

Comment: it seems OP wants to get the ratio between headcount and total (i.e. is is expecting to get a number between 0 and1). Alaso, note that as OP you are using integer division, losing all decimal values resulting from division

Comment: @GianPaolo, Yes right. Edited answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt cast headcount or input to a float before doing the division. It is currently doing integer division, which does not include any remainders. headcount/input is the same as 2201/4321 which will equal 0 in integer division. Cast them to floats by doing result = (float)headcount/(float)input.